# iterating through data and splitting into different categories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a problem with organising my data in python. Basically I have a csv file of data, formatted as below:

```
Direction(Deg), Speed(m/s)
10, 2.8
20, 3.2
45, 5.2
.., ..
.., ..
360, 20
```

So the problem im having with this is that I am trying to categorise the data into separate lists, so for example a list of the directions and speeds between 45 and 67.5, degrees at 2 - 3 m/s. There is 16 different direction ranges in 22.5 degrees increments, and 30 different speed ranges at 1 m/s increments.

I suppose I could some up my main problems into two:
1. How could I produce the needed lists without manually writing out what will top over hundred lists, is it possible to automate this?
2. how can I loop through the data to extract the numbers I need into the appropriate lists, so far I've been trying to do a for loop within a for loop, as below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20]

for number in xrange(0,20,2):
    for value in a:
         if value >= number -2 and value < number:
             print value
```

However I can't think of a way to solve the problem of creating the lists from the first part of my question.

Sorry for the terrible wording of this.. I'm still very new to using python and as you might be able to tell I haven't quite got my head around this problem! any information to point me in the right direction would be useful!

Comment: Just checking back: did you understand my solution? Can I clarify anything? If it was the best solution to your problem, please tick it as the solution - this rewards me for assisting you. If you found a better solution, you can also enter that as an answer below.

Comment: Hi, Yes that solution was definitely useful thankyou. However I ended up using numpy and the digitize function to index everything and get it into the form I needed.  Defaultdict achieved effectively the same thing it just proved easier to work with the data in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

INPUT = "myfile.csv"
ANGLE_SZ = 22.5
SPEED_SZ = 1.

def read_csv(fname, skip_header=False, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, "rb") as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        if skip_header:
            header = next(incsv, None)
        for row in incsv:
            yield row

def main():
    data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    for d,s in read_csv(INPUT, skip_header=True):
        data[int(d/ANGLE_SZ)][int(s/SPEED_SZ)].append((d,s))

    # data[][] now contains all your data, sorted into buckets

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```